# Configure Cisco 5508 WLC with Internal DHCP and external DHCP

Tags: cisco, wlc

I have configured a Cisco WLC 5508 to use the internal DHCP server and a windows NPS server. So far, all is working fine.

However, I want to use EAP authentication with an external DHCP server.  How can I achieve that, while still maintaining the internal DHCP server on the WLC for specific clients.

Please help

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way to achieve this would be to separate the clients into different SSIDs/WLANs.   Place the clients who need addresses from the Built-In DHCP server in one, and the clients who need addresses from the External DHCP server into another.

This way, you could point the Proxy DHCP server IP address wherever you need it to go depeding on which client is requesting an address.

(In my current environment at $DAYJOB, we're utilizing a similar configuration.  We're actually sending the proxy DHCP request to 3 different locations depending on the SSID.)

You could change the destination for the DHCP requests either on the Interface corresponding to the WLAN or on the Advanced tab of the WLAN itself.